# C++ code If condition meaning in Fortran or Python

Tags: python, c++, fortran

I've been trying to read through a C++ code and was wondering if anyone could help.
So, is the snippet:

```
bool res;
if(res=(D<0)) {u2_=u2= C>0 ? atan2(A,B) : atan2(-A,-B); D=0;}
 else
 {
  D = sqrt(D);
  const realfp err = M*y1_+N*x1_-data.K*y1_*x1_;
  const realfp err_= M*y2_+N*x2_-data.K*y2_*x2_;

  if(fabs(err)<fabs(err_)) {
    u2 = atan2(y1_, x1_);
    u2_= atan2(y2_, x2_);}
  else {
    u2_= atan2(y1_, x1_);
    u2 = atan2(y2_, x2_);}

 }
```

Equivalent to:

```
res = D < 0;
if (res) {
    if (C > 0) {
        u2_ = u2 = atan(A, B);
    } else {
        u2_ = u2 = atan2(-A, -B);
    }
    D = 0;
} else {
    D = sqrt(D);
    const realfp err  = M*y1_+N*x1_-data.K*y1_*x1_;
    const realfp err_ = M*y2_+N*x2_-data.K*y2_*x2_;

    if (fabs(err) < fabs(err_)) {
        u2 = atan2(y1_, x1_);
        u2_= atan2(y2_, x2_);
    } else {
        u2_= atan2(y1_, x1_);
        u2 = atan2(y2_, x2_);
    }
}
```

The reason I am asking is because I am confused with the condition `if(res=(D<0)) {u2_=u2= C>0 ? atan2(A,B) : atan2(-A,-B); D=0;}` 
I understand that it checks if D<0 but can't follow afterwords, especially the part `{u2_=u2= C>0 ? atan2(A,B) : atan2(-A,-B); D=0;}`.
In fact, it'll be great if you could translate that `if condition` to either python or Fortran.
Any help will be very much appreciated!

Comment: First, this is horrible code. Second, your rewrite is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
{u2_=u2= C>0 ? atan2(A,B) : atan2(-A,-B); D=0;}
```

can be translated to this:

```
if (C >0) {
  u2_ = u2 = atan2(A,B);
}
else {
  u2_ = u2 = atan2(-A,-B);
}
D=0;
```

Comment: Thank you so much but what exactly is equal to atan2(A,B). Shouldn't it be of the form `something=atan2(A,B)`?

Comment: I'm sorry that I made a mistake and I've just edited my answer

Comment: @Pete Becker Do you mean that u2=C if C>0 and D<0?

Comment: @Abedin -- no. The **edited** code is correct. My (deleted) comment was about the earlier version. Your rewrite **in your question** is also correct.